# How to parse user input to new component in angular on submit?

Tags: angular

I have a simple form with form validations. I want to display the user input in another component but  I am unsure of how to do so. I would like to use @Input to parse the info from one component to another. Im not quite sure how to implement it despite reading about it online.

html

```
<form [formGroup]="checkOutForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
                <div class="input-container">
                    <div><label></label></div>
                    <input size="50" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
                </div>
                <div class="error-list" *ngIf="fc.name.errors && isSubmitted">
                    <div *ngIf="fc.name.errors.required">Should not be empty</div>


                </div>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <div><label></label></div>
                    <input size="50" type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
                </div>
                <div class="error-list" *ngIf="fc.email.errors && isSubmitted">
                    <div *ngIf="fc.email.errors.required">Should not be empty</div>
                    <div *ngIf="fc.email.errors.email">Email is not correct</div>

                </div>

                <div class="input-container">
                    <div><label></label></div>
                    <input size="50" type="address" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address">
                </div>
                <div class="error-list" *ngIf="fc.address.errors && isSubmitted">
                    <div *ngIf="fc.address.errors.required">Should not be empty</div>
                </div>


                <br>
                <div class="button"></div>
                <button type="submit">Submit Order Details</button>
            </form>
```

ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { CartService } from '../cart.service';
import { Cart } from '../models/Cart';
import { Order } from '../models/Order';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout-page',
  templateUrl: './checkout-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout-page.component.css']
})
export class CheckoutPageComponent implements OnInit {
  order:Order = new Order();
  checkOutForm!: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  

  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder,cartService: CartService,private route: Router) {
    const cart = cartService.getCart();
    this.order.items = cart.items;
    this.order.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice;
    

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.checkOutForm = this.formbuilder.group({
     
      name: ['', [Validators.required],],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      address: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
    //loginForm.controls.email
    //use getter property instead
    //fc.email
  }
  get fc() {
    return this.checkOutForm.controls;
  }
  submit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.checkOutForm.invalid)
      return
     
      console.log(`name: ${this.fc.name.value},email: ${this.fc.email.value},address: ${this.fc.address.value}`);
    alert('Your order has been placed! Order will be delivered upon successful payment.')
    this.route.navigate(['/order-summary']);
    
  }






}
```

Just ignore the cart service and models

Answer (score 0):

If the component in which you want to display the info is in the CheckoutPageComponent, let's assume this component is named ChildComponent. I will also assume that the info you want to pass is the property "name". The way to take it as input in the ChildComponent is as follows:

1. Add the ChildComponent to the template and pass the name property.

CheckoutPageComponent.html

```
...
<app-child [name]="fc.name.value"></app-child>
...
```

2. Create the ChildComponent

ChildComponent.html

```
<p *ngIf="name">{{name}}</p>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
...
export class ChildComponent {
...
    @Input() name: string | undefined = undefined;
...
}
```

Comment: do i have to add anything in the parent component?

Comment: Step 1. of my answer describes what you have to add to the parent (CheckoutPageComponent). Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I edited my answer as there was an error in step 1 @codelala

Comment: im still unable to print the input value in the child component :( the value isnt getting printed

Answer (score 0):

So you want your  show your order detail in  **order-summary**

1. If you want to use **@Input** then it must be your **order-summary** component selector used in your **CheckoutPageComponent** HTML Then you can use @Input.Basically it will work only when you have parent ,child relation between the component
2. If your component is not in relation then use services.[enter link description here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#add-getheroes) save your data in services and use that in your **CheckoutPageComponent**